# Subscribing to event inside a method while passing extra parameters from this method without using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

So I have an event signature like this:

```
public event EventHandler<OnColorChangedEventArgs> onColorChanged;

public class OnColorChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Color color;
}
```

and a method I want to subscribe to the event like this:

```
private void UpdateColor(object sender, RayCaster.OnColorChangedEventArgs eventArgs, PositionOnLine positionOnLine)
{
    if (positionOnLine == PositionOnLine.Start)
    {
        _lineRenderer.startColor = eventArgs.color;
    }
    else
    {
        _lineRenderer.endColor = eventArgs.color;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the subscribing method requires more parameters than the event invocation passes. Those extra parameters should be passed from a method I call to subscribe to the event in the first place, like this:

```
public void AddPoint(RayCaster rayCaster, PositionOnLine positionOnLine, Transform transform)
{
    //some irrelevant code

    rayCaster.onColorChanged += (sender, args) => UpdateColor(sender, args, positionOnLine);
}
```

This works as I want it to. However, as far as I understand it, this is an anonymous delegate.
And I need to unsubscribe from this method at some point. I can't seem to find a way to turn this into a non-anonymous delegate. I'm pretty new to delegates and events, so please point out any code smells. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate signature must match, so: you can't cheat here. If you genuinely need to unsubscribe later, you can store the delegate instance somewhere, i.e.

```cs
EventHandler<OnColorChangedEventArgs> handler = (sender, args) =>
     UpdateColor(sender, args, positionOnLine);
rayCaster.onColorChanged += handler;
// ... and later
rayCaster.onColorChanged -= handler;
```

Comment: I don't think I fully comprehend your solution.
I might not have been clear, but the event declaration and the UpdateColor methods are in separate classes.
Where in the code would I declare that handler? Because the OnColorChangedEventArgs is not a recognized type in the class with the UpdateColor method declaration.

Comment: @Thrindil yes, they usually are, otherwise there wouldn't be any point using an event! My example was based on your `AddPoint` method; however, `OnColorChangedEventArgs` is absolutely accessible - you might just be missing a `using` directive or a qualification; try pressing `Ctrl`+`. ` on it - the IDE can usually add that for you.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake in my declaration. I added handler as a class variable and assigned it inside the AddPoint method which allows me to unsubscribe from it in another method. Works like a charm.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a local function like this:

```
public void AddPoint(RayCaster rayCaster, PositionOnLine positionOnLine, Transform transform)
{
    //some irrelevant code

    void updateColor(object sender, OnColorChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateColor(sender, e, positionOnLine);
    }

    rayCaster.onColorChanged += updateColor;
    rayCaster.onColorChanged -= updateColor;
}
```

By the way: The event should not be named like on..., but just e.g. ColorChanged.

Comment: Okay. In which cases would the 'On' prefix be added?

Comment: It is not a strict rule, but convention. Typically the event publisher (the class raising the event) would have a protected virtual method named On[YourEventName], e.g. OnColorChanged, which will actually raise the event (in your case ColorChanged). See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines) for an example in the MSDN docs.

Comment: Thank you, seems like I have the convention wrong indeed.
One question though, as the event is invoked in the class of which this event is a member, I wouldn't need this protected virtual method, because it is only required to invoke the event from another class, right?

Comment: As mentioned in the docs it is _to allow derived classes to override the event invocation behavior_ . It's not intended to be called by other classes an only subclasses can see this method.